# Aggregate data from view as UDF to use in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an existing view that returns data in the following format.

```
option_name           product_id

XSMALL (2-6)          17854
SMALL (6-10)          17854
MEDIUM (10-14)      17854
LARGE                 18232
```

How do I return this data in a comma separated field formatted like this, based on sending a product_id to the function?

XSMALL (2-6), SMALL (6-10), MEDIUM (10-14)

I am using MS SQL 2k5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` in SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetProductNames(@ProductID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
SELECT
    Options = SUBSTRING((
        SELECT ', ' + o2.option_name
        FROM options AS o2
        WHERE o2.product_id = o1.product_id
        FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 1000)
FROM options AS o1
WHERE o1.product_id = @ProductID
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, can you wrap this in a UDF create statement, having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Lol @Mitch... exact same code with a 3-line function header. :P

Comment: if the post was helpful how come you haven't upvoted? +1 from me.

Comment: I think this needs to be a scalar function since I am trying to use the returned value as a field in another query as part of a select statement.  Can this be easily converted to a scalar function?

Answer (score 0):

**

> declare @option_name varchar(1000)
>   select @option_name =
>   isnull(@option_name+',','') +
>   option_name  from tablename select
>   @option_name

**