# How to aggregate data into view with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing view that returns data in the following format based on aggregating option names that have the same product_id.   The view name is "vProdOptions"

```
option_name           product_id

XSMALL (2-6)          17854
SMALL (6-10)          17854
MEDIUM (10-14)      17854
LARGE                 18232
```

How do I return this data in an aggregated view formatted like this?

```
  OPTIONS_AVAIL                                           Product_ID

  XSMALL (2-6), SMALL (6-10), MEDIUM (10-14)              127182

  SMALL (6-10), MEDIUM (10-14)                            166382
```

I am using MS SQL 2k5.

I am creating a new question here based on comments from these two questions. I realized that I needed a view instead.

[Aggregate data from view as UDF to use in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233740/aggregate-data-from-view-as-udf-to-use-in-select-statement)

[error with sql function creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239375/error-with-sql-function-creation)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651608/sql-joining-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the distinct products, and `cross apply` them on a function that computes a string of options:

```
select *
from (select distinct product_id from @t) a
cross apply (
    select option_name + ', ' as [text()]
    from @t b
    where a.product_id = b.product_id
    for xml path('')
) c ( Options )

-->

product_id   Options
17854        XSMALL (2-6), SMALL (6-10), MEDIUM (10-14), 
18232        LARGE,
```

Code to create example:

```
declare @t table (option_name varchar(30), product_id int)

insert @t select 'XSMALL (2-6)', 17854
union all select 'SMALL (6-10)', 17854
union all select 'MEDIUM (10-14)', 17854
union all select 'LARGE', 18232
```

Comment: Hi Andomar, I just included a small sampling of data in my sample set. There are hundreds of options which would prevent using union in the way you described.

Comment: Hi Jeff: the unions are just to create a test table variable named `@t`.  To calculate the result set, you only need the first query. Replace `@t` with the name of your options table

Comment: Works great Andomar, thank you very much. Is there a way to avoid the trailing comma?

Comment: Cheers.  You can remove the trailing comma by replacing `select *` with `select product_id, substring(Options,1,len(Options)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Pivoting is not a terribly efficient way to go in SQL. Personally, I'd leave your view alone and pivot the data through the application.

Comment: The requested "feature" belongs to UI consideration, and not storage logic, so it doesn't make much sense to do it in SQL.

Comment: When you pivot you combine multiple rows into one row.  F.e. a row "date, value" becomes "year, janValue, febValue, decValue, ..." Totally unrelated to this question?